Windows Server 2022 - Time Offset for System User
I am running a Windows Server 2022 as a file server with CIFS and NFS share.
The main share is also backed up with the tool UrBackup (see urbackup.org).
The tool runs as a service with the user "SYSTEM".
The time is correctly set up and also the time zone is correct with UTC +1h.
The correct time shows up in the system tray clock and with the time stramps of new files.
I checked the time as "Administrator" user and my normal local user, everything fine.
However the UrBackup tool shows all time stamps to with an offset of one hour in the future.
This made me think, maybe the time zone is not set correctly for the SYSTEM user?
Anybody knows insights how windows handles this?
Thanks.
